# How to HTML encode/escape a string? Is there a built-in?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, encode

I have an untrusted string that I want to show as text in an HTML page. I need to escape the chars '`<`' and '`&`' as HTML entities.  The less fuss the better.

I'm using UTF8 and don't need other entities for accented letters.

Is there a built-in function in Ruby or Rails, or should I roll my own?

Comment: [According to the OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content), the following six characters should be escaped for proper XSS protection in HTML element content: `&<>"'/`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `h` helper method:

```
<%=h "<p> will be preserved" %>
```

Comment: Well, it also escapes >, which is unnecessary, but it'll do.

Comment: You can use parentheses to print some with h and some without. <%= h("<p") + ">" %>

Comment: Now that would be silly. I don't care much if it gets escaped or not. I'm just noting it's not required per the html specs.

Comment: It's *occasionally* required in XHTML due to the XML spec's rather annoying insistence that ‘]]>’ be kept out of text (see the ‘CharData’ production). This makes it generally easier (and harmless) to always escape it.

Comment: for those interested `h` is an alias for `html_escape`

Comment: It's defined in `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb

Answer (score 157):

Checkout the Ruby [CGI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000067) class. There are methods to encode and decode HTML as well as URLs.

```
CGI::escapeHTML('Usage: foo "bar" <baz>')
# => "Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great since it can be done from the controllers. Not that I'd do that, of course.

Comment: This is useful in functional/integration tests, for checking the correctness of content inserted into a template (when the content is supposed to be HTML-escaped).

Comment: If the content is being displayed in a clients website, other then your own (where you cant control the view), whats the problem with escaping the html before inserting into the database? Is there another work around?

Comment: Right - escaping before entering into the database is great.  You just want to make sure you don't have any old un-escaped hacks in there from before you added it...

Comment: I like its synonym more: [CGI.escape_html](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/CGI/escape_html/class)

Answer (score 79):

In Ruby on Rails 3 HTML will be escaped by default.

For non-escaped strings use:

```
<%= raw "<p>hello world!</p>" %>
```

Answer (score 29):

[ERB::Util.html_escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) can be used  anywhere. It is available without using `require` in Rails.

Comment: this is actually using `CGI.escapeHTML` underneath

Comment: @akostadinov - the result is different however. For instance, ERB::Util.html_escape will turn apostrophes into &#x27; whereas CGI::escapeHTML will not

Comment: @LouisSayers, I can't see how that can happen:
```
[43] pry(main)> show-source ERB::Util.html_escape

From: /usr/share/ruby/erb.rb @ line 945:
Owner: #<Class:ERB::Util>
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def html_escape(s)
  CGI.escapeHTML(s.to_s)
end
```

Comment: @akostadinov - hmm... Just ran again and yes, they produced the same output. I swear this produced different results when I ran this at work (perhaps different erb / cgi version behaviour?). I'll have to see why I got a different result at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 19):

An addition to Christopher Bradford's answer to use the HTML escaping anywhere,
since most people don't use `CGI` nowadays, you can also use `Rack`:

```
require 'rack/utils'
Rack::Utils.escape_html('Usage: foo "bar" <baz>')
```

Comment: Is there a better way to escape strings in a similar way in model instance methods?

Comment: I think this Rack::Utils existed only until version 2.3 or something.

Comment: @akostadinov I have just verified that as of today's version of rack (2.2.3), November 2021, the escaping functionality is still included in the gem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was confused by bad docs site UI.

Answer (score 16):

You can use either `h()` or `html_escape()`, but most people use `h()` by convention.  `h()` is short for `html_escape()` in rails.

In your controller:

```
@stuff = "<b>Hello World!</b>"
```

In your view:

```
<%=h @stuff %>
```

If you view the HTML source: you will see the output without actually bolding the data.  I.e. it is encoded as `&lt;b&gt;Hello World!&lt;/b&gt;`.

It will appear an be displayed as `<b>Hello World!</b>`

Answer (score 13):

Comparaison of the different  methods:

```
> CGI::escapeHTML("quote ' double quotes \"")
=> "quote &#39; double quotes &quot;"

> Rack::Utils.escape_html("quote ' double quotes \"")
=> "quote &#x27; double quotes &quot;"

> ERB::Util.html_escape("quote ' double quotes \"")
=> "quote &#39; double quotes &quot;"
```

I wrote my own to be compatible with Rails ActiveMailer escaping:

```
def escape_html(str)
  CGI.escapeHTML(str).gsub("&#39;", "'")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`h()` is also useful for escaping quotes.

For example, I have a view that generates a link using a text field `result[r].thtitle`. The text could include single quotes. If I didn't escape `result[r].thtitle` in the confirm method, the Javascript would break:

```
&lt;%= link_to_remote "#{result[r].thtitle}", :url=>{ :controller=>:resource,
:action         =>:delete_resourced,
:id     => result[r].id,
:th     => thread,                                                                                                      
:html       =>{:title=> "<= Remove"},                                                       
:confirm    => h("#{result[r].thtitle} will be removed"),                                                   
:method     => :delete %>

&lt;a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('docs: add column &amp;apos;dummy&amp;apos; will be removed')) { new Ajax.Request('/resource/delete_resourced/837?owner=386&amp;th=511', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'delete', parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('ou812')}); }; return false;" title="&lt;= Remove">docs: add column 'dummy'</a>
```

Note: the `:html` title declaration is magically escaped by Rails.