# Display HTML tags as HTML in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have controller method:

```
def do_it
   @result = "some <b>another</b>"

   respond_to do | format |  
        format.js {render :layout => false}  
   end
end
```

And do_it.js.erb:

```
$( "#in" ).html("<b>hello</b> <br /> <%= @result %>");
```

When I call this method I'll get 'hello' as bold text, but 'another' as ordinary text with  tags in my browser.

[image]

I need to hide all html tags and display 'another' as bold text. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%= %> escapes the HTML code by default. You can prevent it from doing this by:

```
$( "#in" ).html("<b>hello</b> <br /> <%= raw @result %>");
```

or

```
@result = "some <b>another</b>".html_safe()
```

Comment: Thanks! You return my believe in Rails :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about ruby, but I came on this post that might be relevant to your problem:

1-[rails: how to html encode/escape a string? is there a built-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692921/rails-how-to-html-encode-escape-a-string-is-there-a-built-in)

2-[How do I encode/decode HTML entities in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby)

I think you should html-encode your original string

```
@result = "some <b>another</b>"
```

then html-decode it when displaying it.
Good Luck