# HTML Not Rendering over API in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, api

This is a cool problem. I have some videos on Wistia. I ask for the videos and I embed them into the site. That was fun. Now I want to grab the description. This is what I got:

```
<p> This is a description.</p>
```

I was expecting those `<p>` tags not to actually render as HTML. I'm assuming this is for security reasons.

One solution is to remove the tags with a reg ex and wrap around manually. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: This should help: [rails: how to html encode/escape a string? is there a built-in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692921/rails-how-to-html-encode-escape-a-string-is-there-a-built-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you could just sanitize it:

in a controller:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize st, tags: %w()
```

in a view you can just

```
<%= sanitize st, tags: %w() %>
```