# How to show some HTML entities on title tag using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, ruby-on-rails-4.2, sanitize

I'm running Rails 4.2.x and I have the following problem.

The `<title>` of some pages are generated from user content. So I have to use the `sanitize` Rails helpers to properly clean it up.

But if the user writes something like "A & B", the title shown in browser is `A &amp; B` which is wrong.

What's the correct way of escaping user content on the `<title>` tag using Rails? At least some special characters should be included...

Comment: `<%= title.html_safe %>` should help. And see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Comment: @devanand html_safe marks the user input as safe, whatever it contains... so that's the unsafest approach :-)

Comment: the link I gave you to read, explains how to make user input more secure!

Comment: @devanand I know how to make the input more secure, and in general, `sanitize` works great when we inject user input in the middle of the HTML. However in this case, the `<title>` tag is sensitive to HTML entities, so I don't want some of them to be escaped.

Comment: that's what I'd like to tell. use `strip_tags` in that case. or did I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

We can use [CGi](http://apidock.com/ruby/CGI)
also

```
title =  "A & B"
=> "A & B"
string = CGI.escapeHTML(title)
=> "A &amp; B" 
string = CGI.unescapeHTML(title)
=> "A & B"
```

Rails providing so many options to escape

Refer these links:

[raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)

[How to HTML encode/escape a string? Is there a built-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692921/rails-how-to-html-encode-escape-a-string-is-there-a-built-in)

If you want remove tags you can use [SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

One more option : [WhiteListSanitizer](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/WhiteListSanitizer.html)

```
white_list_sanitizer = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new
white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(s, tags: %w())
white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(s, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style))
```

You can use [Rails::Html::TargetScrubber](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer#railshtmltargetscrubber) also

Comment: `CGI.unescapeHTML("<script>alert('Hello');</script>")` returns `<script>alert('hello')</script>`, not very safe :-)

Comment: Do you want remove html tags or script tag

Comment: I want to sanitize user input, so I don't be attacked by XSS

Comment: yes, that's what I've described in the question. It works great for injecting user content in the middle of html, but since it escapes html entities, it breaks my `<title>` tag.

Comment: try this string.gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "")

Comment: I was expecting a more standard/proven solution inside Rails in 2016

Comment: Otherwise try WhiteListSanitizer.

Comment: @WtrKanna did you even try the examples you posted? It still encodes the `&` as `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

You can both sanitize and convert html entities to proper characters with a combination of sanitize and the htmlentities gem. This works for me in the console:

`gem install htmlentities`

then...

```
c = ActionController::Base::ApplicationController.new
dirty_content = "<script>content & tags</script>"
clean_but_with_entities = c.helpers.sanitize(dirty_content)
nice_looking = HTMLEntities.new.decode(clean_but_with_entities.to_str )
```

You end up with "content & tags". To make this easier to use I put this in application_controller:

```
helper_method :sanitize_and_decode
def sanitize_and_decode(str)
  helpers.sanitize(str)
  HTMLEntities.new.decode(str.to_str)
end
```

(to_str is to work around the SafeBuffer issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities/issues/13))