# Rails - How to only escape <script> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I see
+ html_escape: escape all tags.
+ sanitize: remove all tags what isn't in whilelist.

Now, I want only escape script tag, not escapse other tags.

Do you have a solution ? Thanks all!

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Iam using Rails 4.2.5

Comment: Refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625464/how-to-show-some-html-entities-on-title-tag-using-rails/35626493#35626493

Comment: Just as a reminder - JavaScript can be embedded into other tags as well, not just `<script>`, so be aware of what you leave unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

As you are on rails 4.2.5, you can use https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer which gets installed with rails. You can do following to escape only script tag.

```
scrubber = Rails::Html::TargetScrubber.new
scrubber.tags = ['script']

html_fragment = Loofah.fragment('<script></script><div></div>')
html_fragment.scrub!(scrubber)
html_fragment.to_s # outputs "<div></div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string = '<html> <title> <head> <script type="javascript"></script> </head> </title> </html>'

 string.gsub(/<script.*[\s\S]*\/script>/,"")

 => "<html> <title> <head>  </head> </title> </html>"
```

**Update**

If you are using Rails 4.2.5 you may need this.

[Rails::HTML::TargetScrubber](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer#railshtmltargetscrubber)

Answer (score 0):

Rails providing so many options for string / HTML entities

```
  s = "<script>alert('Hello');</script>"
```

option : [WhiteListSanitizer](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/WhiteListSanitizer.html)

```
 white_list_sanitizer = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new
 white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(s, tags: %w())
 white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(s, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style))
  => "alert('Hello');"
```

Refer this link alse

[How to show some HTML entities on title tag using Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625464/how-to-show-some-html-entities-on-title-tag-using-rails/35626493#35626493)

Answer (score -2):

```
string.gsub!(/<(?=script)||(?<=script)>/) {|x| "#\{x}"}
```