# Is there a conflict with this code and FancyBox3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox-3

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this section of code? I recently got this to work, but found out soon after the functionality for the Fancybox gallery stopped working. The a link element is only a sliver compared to the over all element. Im not sure if thats it. I know the most recent edit I made was to fix the surrounding row from .row-fluid to .row since that broke my layout. Below is the code:

```
    <body id="portfolio"> 
     <div class="container-fluid" id="particles-js"></div>
      <%= render 'layouts/altmenu_gallery' %>
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>

        <div id="gallery" class="container-fluid">
          <% @photos.each_slice(4) do |group| %>
            <div class="row ">
              <% group.compact.each do |photo| %>
                  <div class= "col-md-3">
                    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery" href="<%=image_path photo.file_url %>" data-caption="<%=  photo.description %>"> 
                      <%= image_tag photo.file_url, class:' img-fluid img-thumbnail'  if photo.file.present? %>
                     </a>
                  </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <br class="clear">
          </div>


        <%= link_to 'New Photo', new_photo_path %>
   </body>
```

Comment: how are you instantiating fancybox? I guess you run some javascript at page load

Comment: Sorry just getting back I have it in the assets folder. Im gonna update with the full page code if I can soon.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it is not possible to tell without seeing the actual html code or, preferably, live demo. Maybe this issue arises because you have not escaped `photo.description` and that breaks html code, but, as I said, I can not be sure.

Comment: Hi Janis, how do you escape properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692921/how-to-html-encode-escape-a-string-is-there-a-built-in