# special characters in title of charts of Charts Js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-5, chart.js

I am using [Charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) to display bar graphs and bubble charts.
However, my titles for these graphs contain '&' but it is shown as &
How can I avoid this so that '&' is displayed as it is in the labels and titles of charts.
Below is my code:

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bubble',
        data: {
            datasets: data_sets
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                fontSize: 20,
                text: '<%= group.first&.name%>'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/692926/7619578 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252113/7619578 might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

`<%= group.first&.name %>`

with

`<%= group.first&.name&.html_safe %>`

in the text of the title fixed the issue for me.